# Xamarin.UITest Query elements inside of a SFSafariViewController and ChromeCustomTabs

Tags: c#, xamarin, chrome-custom-tabs, sfsafariviewcontroller, xamarin.uitest

We are currently implementing Open Id Connect in our Xamarin App. Therefore we also want to adjust the UI-Tests to do the login inside of a browser with Xamarin.UITest.

But when we try to query the username and password input fields with the `c => c.CSS(".css-selector")` selector like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-webviews) no results are returned. This is happening inside of **ASWebAuthenticationSession** on iOS and as well on **ChromeCustomTabs** on Android.

Here the code for selecting the elements:

```
            App.EnterText(c => c.Css("input[type=\"email\"]"), "username");
            App.EnterText(c => c.Css("input[type=\"password\"]"), "password");
            App.DismissKeyboard(); // On smaller screen the login button might be hidden below the keyboard otherwise
            App.Tap(c => c.Css("button[type=\"submit\"]"));
```

I also tried to use another selector like "div" or  "body" but nothing is returned.

The error looks like this `Unable to enter text. Query for Css("input[type="email"]") gave no results.`

In the end is for iOS a `SFSafariView` rendered as here in the tree output.

```
[CalabashRootView > UIWindow]                                                                        
  [UITransitionView > UIDropShadowView]
    [UIView > UIScrollView]
      [UIView]
        [UIImageView] id: "login_logo.png"
        [UIView]
          [UIImageView] id: "loading_spinner.png"
      [_UIScrollViewScrollIndicator > UIView] label: "Vertical scroll bar, 1 page",  text: "0%" (center not on screen)
      [_UIScrollViewScrollIndicator > UIView] label: "Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page",  text: "0%" (center not on screen)
    [UIDimmingView]
  [UITransitionView]
    [UIDimmingView]
    [UIDropShadowView > ... > SFSafariView]
      [SFSafariLaunchPlaceholderView]
        [UINavigationBar]
          [_UIBarBackground]
            [_UIBarBackgroundShadowView > _UIBarBackgroundShadowContentImageView]
            [UIVisualEffectView > _UIVisualEffectBackdropView]
          [_UINavigationBarContentView]
        [UIToolbar > _UIBarBackground] id: "Toolbar"
          [_UIBarBackgroundShadowView > _UIBarBackgroundShadowContentImageView]
          [UIVisualEffectView > _UIVisualEffectBackdropView]
      [_UISizeTrackingView]
        [_UIRemoteView] id: "RemoteViewBridge"
```

Am I missing a step or is there another way to test those scenarios?

Comment: Can you also share the tree for Android? UITest for web views haven’t been the most successful. I would suggest placing a check so that it skips the open id authentication during UITests

Comment: I opened a ticket at Microsoft: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/appcenter-docs/issues/859 however I don't think they know if it works themselves.

Comment: I am having the same issue. i want to write a uitest for an oauth process inside a chrome custom tab, but i have no means of accessing it with app.query(). 
Is there anything new on this topic? i could not find any solution in the web so far.

Comment: I think it's not possible and should actually not be possible to access those save browsers. Anyway, we implemented a backdoor to inject a webkit WebView as the browser for authentication. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/features/backdoors

Comment: If you access the page in a desktop browser you can see the html classes.  you can access using the .Class() and .CSS() methods

Comment: @shookdiesel - this is exactly this is not working inside of the safe web views. Which actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to read out safe web views. These web views were created so that users could log in inside a safe environment to which the App itself has no access. So it's a good thing the queries do not work.

Either use a [backdoor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/features/backdoors) to inject an unsafe web view for the UI tests or use the [Client Credentials flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow) if you need a token to communicate with your API. The production apps should use [PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce), though.